# vue.js does setter/getter happen for props too?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say I have a parent component where I initialize an array variable in data property of Vue. Then I pushed 10,000 object elements into this array. This means that each property of each object of this array will have setter/getter that Vue made for us.

Now, let's say I pass this array to child component as a prop.

Question 1)

Child component

```
props:{
  passedArray
},

data(){
  return { 
    childArray:[]
  }
}
created(){
   this.childArray = passedArray
}
```

Now, as I made new array and get it equal to prop array, will vue make new setters/getters for each property of each object of childArray? because when vue sees array equality and array is described in data, it makes setters/getters for everyone. **If it won't make setter/getter, then does it check if passed array's objects have setter/getter already set?**

**Does this mean that this child component's code won't grow Memory (RAM) At all?**

2) what if I make something like this in Child component

```
created(){
   this.childArray = [].concat(passedArray); 
}
```

**what about now? will it make new setters/getters or won't?**

**this will grow RAM a little bit as childArray now have to store references of objects from passedArray. and in previous case, it just has to make it equal to passed array. Right?**

Question 3)

In my opinion, it doesn't create new setters/getters at all for props data if passed props is an object or array, but I saw initProps in vue source code, and what it does is it still creates setter/getter for each prop options. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you guessed, Vue doesn't create additional getters or setters if the object is already reactive, but your root data items will always have their own independent getters/setters.

For arrays, Vue checks if each object item is reactive and if it is not, it will make it so.

So both statements won't actually create new getters or setters. However, if the `passedArray` is a result of something like an API call  (outside of Vue.js reactivity) then it will be created for each object item.

EDIT: Q3

`initProps` only defines the props on the component prototype, it doesn't make them reactive. If you want to check out how reactivity is done you could take a look at `src/core/observer/index.js` in the Vue source.

Comment: I edited the question, take a look at my 3rd question. Does that function only execute if passed prop data is primitive type?

Comment: I added a note on Q3